# Decorate a class with Python that prints the int variables of the decorated class

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm studying for a python course and one of the exercise was to create a decorator for this class that returns every int variables.`

```
@decoratoreDiClasse
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 'w'`
```

My problem is that the list is always empty beacuse dict does not return the variables inside init,how can i solve my problem? 
i've written my decorator below

```
def decoratoreDiClasse(cls):
def elencaVariabili():

    lista = []
    print(cls)
    lista1 = cls.__dict__
    print(lista1)

    for ab in lista1:

        if isinstance(ab, int):
            lista.append(ab)
    return lista

setattr(cls, "elencaVariabili", elencaVariabili())
return cls
```

here's the part of the main that should print the variables,I cannot change anything apart from "decoratoreDiClasse" due to the teacher request.

```
    for v in x.elencaVariabili():
    print(v, end=' ')
```

Comment: a hint: `lista1 = cls.__dict__` will not have any instance attributes, which is what you care about...

Comment: is your hint about "cls" or __dict__?

Comment: The hint was about using the `__dict__` attribute of `cls`. Class namespaces do not contain instance attributes, they contain class attributes. You would need an instance for the instance attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're supposed to have your decorator add a method to the class that prints out integer-valued attributes on an instance it's called on. That's not what you're currently trying to do, as your code tries to find the variables *on the class* instead of on an instance later on.

Think of what you're doing as a method, and it will be a lot simpler:

```
def decoratoreDiClasse(cls):
    def elencaVariabili(self):     # this is a method, so it should take self!
        lista = [value for value in self.__dict__.values()  # loop over our attribute values
                       if isinstance(value, int)]           # and pick out the integers!
        return lista

    setattr(cls, "elencaVariabili", elencaVariabili)  # don't call the method here
    return cls
```

It's not entirely clear from your code if you're supposed to be returning the names of the integer variables or just the values themselves. I went with just the values, but if you need the variable names, you may need to change the list comprehension to iterate over the `items()` of the instance's dictionary rather than just the `values()`.